# Changing the members of a static exchange distribution list programmatically

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We have an important email distribution list, on exchange 2010, where the members change weekly, based on many work based criteria. Right now we change the members manually, and I would love to automate that change.

So I have the new members from another App's API, and I would love to change the members of our DL. So I using the Exchange API I can get the current members of the group [There are several ways to do it, for example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb645998%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

But for the life of me I am unable to find out a way where I could actually edit/change  members of my distribution list programmatically.

Ideally I would want to empty the current group and put the new members into it, but open to all manner of ideas and methods to do that? Any ideas?

Comment: Just use the web service to communicate with Exchange. Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633709(v=exchg.80).aspx and feel free to come back here if you'll have any problem with it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is that as far as I can find the EWS provides a method to view the members of a DL [see link in my post] - but I cant find anything in there to change the members of that DL.

Comment: In the link you posted you access that DL through Microsoft Outlook then it's a read-only list. If you connect directly to the Exchange web service then you can change them as you prefer, let's use this as starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh532561(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Alas I dont think its possible with the API, which is downright weird! I can read the group using the ExpandGroup method in EWS, but there seems no way to change membership...So off to the murky world of LDAP for me :)

Comment: Good luck! :) (2 to go)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Dynamic Distribution Group? Your use case is asking for it.

If not, you have to invoke Exchange 2010 Management Shell from your app and call Add-DistributionGroupMember. Since you are using C# it should be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use EWS to modify distribution groups this as [per the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn629393%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

> You can use the EWS Managed API or EWS to expand a distribution group,
>   but to create and manage distribution groups, you’ll need to use
>   Exchange Management Shell cmdlets.

So I used this C# [exchange-client](https://github.com/neutmute/exchange-client) library on github which wraps the [Exchange Management Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn629393%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx#bk_UsingEMS).